# InstallHandler not working

Tags: package, install, global-methods

I have created a product and have it as a package and try to install into new env. I have a custom setting i am trying to create records into custom setting after the package get installed but i am not able to get them created. 
my code

```
global class CVFC_InstallClass implements InstallHandler {

global void onInstall(InstallContext CMLeadSetting) {
    if(CMLeadSetting.isPush()){
        CMLeadSetting__c cml = new CMLeadSetting__c(Name = 'CMLead Conversion');
        insert cml;
    }
}
```

}

Please guide me what i am doing right

Comment: When you say "install" it sounds like an upgrade/clean install rather than a push, in which case isPush() will return false and the custom setting will not get inserted

Comment: than what condition should i use before insert or should i remove the condition and have it directly in side the method.

Comment: If you remove the condition then it will fail if the record is already in the system.  You should check if it exists with the getInstance method and insert it only if it doesn't.

Comment: ok that is nice ...